# How to know the if the scroll are or widget is consisting data or not in pyqt4

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Here it is sample code.I want to check if the data is there or not in widget and scroll area,How can i check if it has data or not? without consider the label

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys


class List_View(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(List_View, self).__init__(None,QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        auto_search_vbox1 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        le=QtGui.QLabel("hello")
        auto_search_vbox1.addWidget(le)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    tb = List_View()
    tb.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: for what widget you want to check if has data, QLabel?

Comment: data only not Qlabel

Comment: i want to check the widget have data or not ?i don't need  that data you can set label or scroll area or  anything else

Comment: What do you mean by data? Your question is unclear

Comment: data means content in widget

Comment: That's subjective, what do you mean with content ?, for me it can be the color of the text, the text, background color, size, etc., all that is contained.

Comment: sir in this example hello is data of the widget

Comment: Okay, but in other widgets what is the data? If it were a button, what would the data be? If it is a Frame?